# New line after every tag in eclipse when editing jsp files

Tags: eclipse, jsp, code-formatting

When auto-formatting JSP files in Eclipse using Ctrl+Shift+F, it is trying to fit as many tags on a line as possible and then the tag that doesn't fit it will break and place the attributes on the next line.

This is created very messy code, example below.

```
        <div class="type-text"><label for="echo">Project Name: </label> <s:textfield
            id="projectName"
            name="projectName"
            value="Project Name"
        >
        </s:textfield></div>
```

Does anyone know how to format JSP files better?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298024/eclipse-html-editor-each-input-tag-on-the-new-line

Comment: it is possible, see the post here : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298024/eclipse-html-editor-each-input-tag-on-the-new-line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hard, but true: just don't use it. Eclipse is great with Java(EE), but weak with (X)HTML/JSP in general. IntelliJ is better here. In Eclipse you just have to *already* write nice intented (X)HTML/JSP code. You can however configure several parameters in preferences by *Web* > *HTML files* > *Editor*, such as the *Line Width*. But still, it doesn't indent code nicely.

Comment: It really is unusable. I am using the options "Split multiple attributes each on a new line" + "Align final bracket in multi-line element tags" in Web > HTML files > Editor but it's still terrible.
I will have a look at IntelliJ.

Comment: arnt new lines ignored in html? a nuisance but mostly harmless unless u need to do something before output is written. wonder if its fixed in 2014

Comment: Hey @BalusC from five years ago, Eclipse seems to be doing a little better now.

Answer (score 0):

GoTo->Preferences->Web->HTML files->Editor
click to uncheck the checkbox of : split multiple attributes each on a new line