# Eclipse HTML Editor: Each <input> tag on the new line

Tags: eclipse

```
<input type="button" value=" 1 " /> 
<input type="button" value=" 2 " /> 
<input type="button" value=" 3 "/>
```

How can I do it?

**EDIT:
Eclipse HTML Editor**

**Ctrl + Shift + F**

I want to use autoformating but after I pressed  **Ctrl + Shift + F** I am getting something like

```
<input type="button" value=" 1 " /> <input type="button" 
                value=" 2 " />
```

[image]

**I want to have each html tag on new line after autoformatting**

Comment: Seems to me like a legit question about how to configure Eclipse.  And I can't find the preference setting to do what the OP asks: how to format the tags on separate lines in the markup, not how to lay out the rendered elements in the browser.

Comment: Seems to me like a legit question about how to configure Eclipse. 
yes, you are right

Comment: Try removing "input" from that list of Inline Elements.

Comment: Weird, this worked for me, make sure you didn't have any override configuration for the same thing.

Comment: I think you should accept the answer by Jay Soyer so that visitors know that is the correct answer.

Answer (score 42):

Removing `input` from the list of inline elements will solve the problem for ya.

Comment: This doesn't work if the parent element is unknown, e.g. in the context of Angular templates (like `<md-input-container>`).

Comment: I had to remove label as well,

Answer (score 1):

Go to Window -> Preferences -> Web -> HTML Files -> Editor
in the right panel set your Line Width to 999
and remove the input in the inline elements list

Answer (score -6):

You can use table even.

```
<table>
<tr><td>
<input type="button" value=" 1 " />
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<input type="button" value=" 2 " />
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<input type="button" value=" 3 "/>
</td></tr>
```

Comment: EDIT: Eclipse HTML Editor

Ctrl + Shift + F

Comment: Adding extra markup isn't what is asked for here. The idea is to configure eclipse formatting correctly rather than work around it. Plus marking up HTML with tables for layout went out with the dinosaurs.

Comment: @MarkChorley This question was edited after answer was given. Individual can be wrong to give answer but may not everyone. Please see timings of answer and question edit.

Comment: @Ketan, it was a bad answer to the original question as well ;)